# How to prevent Windows 11 taskbar child wpf window to be blurred

Tags: c#, wpf

Alright so I have a WPF window and I set it as a child of the Windows 11 Taskbar, my code is below

```
var searchWpf = new SearchWindow(); // wpf window

var wpfWindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(searchWpf).EnsureHandle();

SetParent(wpfWindowHandle, /* Shell_TrayWnd handle */ (IntPtr)0x34DE0);

new System.Windows.Application().Run(searchWpf);
```

My SetParent() function is as follows

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

I checked and my WPF Window really does become the child of the Windows 11 taskbar however it's blurred and seems to be on the back of the taskbar, how do I prevent this?